# How to emit same signal for 2 classess from QThread

Tags: python, pyqt4, qthread

I want to do that:
There is a class called as 'Main'. There is another class called as 'aClass'. And there is a thirth class called as 'Thread'. It is our thread class.
'Main' is our main class and we start our Thread class from Main class.
When our Thread class is started, it emits a signal from run() function...
'Main' and 'aClass' classes try to catch these signals.
'Main' class is able to catch the signal which was emitted from Thread class but 'aClass' can't catch the same signal because I didn't start QThread from 'aClass'. I only defined it in 'aClass'.

Here are codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.aClass = aClass()

        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.printMessage.connect(self.write)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.button = QPushButton("Start Process", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.startProcess)

    def startProcess(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def terminateProcess(self):
        self.thread.terminate()

    def write(self):
        print "Main: hello world..."


class aClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "aClass: I have been started..."
        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.printMessage.connect(self.write)

    def write(self):
        print "aClass: hello world..."

class Thread(QThread):
    printMessage = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        print "Thread: I have been started..."

    def run(self):

        self.printMessage.emit()
        print "Thread: I emitted the message."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = Main()
    root.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The result:
When the program starts, the output is:

```
aClass: I have been started... 
Thread: I have been started...
Thread: I have been started...
```

When I click on 'Start Process' button, the output is:

```
Thread: I emitted the message.
Main: hello world...
```

Total output:

```
aClass: I have been started...
Thread: I have been started...
Thread: I have been started...
Thread: I emitted the message.
Main: hello world...
```

The output that I want to get when I click 'Start Process':

```
Thread: I emitted the message.
Main: hello world...
aClass: hello world...
```

I want this result but I don't want to use self.thread.start() command from 'aClass' because I want to run Thread for only one time...

Comment: Are you trying to get the same signal from the same thread?

Comment: Yes. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is creating a second `Thread` in the `aClass` object which is not the same `Thread` as in the `Main`. You need to connect the signal from the `self.thread` in `Main` to the Slot `write` in your `self.aClass` object.

You want to do this instead:

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.aClass = aClass()

        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.printMessage.connect(self.write)
        self.thread.printMessage.connect(self.aClass.write)


...

class aClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "aClass: I have been started..."
        #self.thread = Thread() #This makes a new Thread
        #self.thread.printMessage.connect(self.write)

    def write(self):
        print "aClass: hello world..."
        self.initUI()
```

Comment: You can also give `self.thread` as argument of `aClass.__init__` to keep the current `connect` line.